# How to list down all available python versions in my windows

Tags: python, version

When I type `py --list` in my cmd, it shows

```
C:\Users\Administrator>py --list
Installed Pythons found by py Launcher for Windows
 -3.9-64 *
 -3.8-64
```

But when I use the command `python` it shows `Python 3.10.6`

```
C:\Users\Administrator>python
Python 3.10.6 (main, Aug 12 2022, 18:00:29)  [GCC 12.1.0 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I am confused about exactly how many pythons are available in my system. How to list them ALL? And how it is decided that which one is default? ( or is there any default way at all? )

Answer (score 2):

Use **py -0** to find all installed versions of python on your PC.

Wallbloggerbeing explained how to change your default.

Answer (score 1):

Advanced System Settings > Advance (tab) . On the bottom you'll find 'Environment Variables'

Double-click on the Path . You'll see path to one of the python installations, change that to path of your desired version.